# Jquery appendTo not working

Tags: jquery

```
var rows = 10; //here's your number of rows and columns
var cols = 23;
var table = $('<table id="tbl"><tbody>');
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="datarow">');
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        $('<td>Data</td>').appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(table); 
}

//table.appendTo('body');
table.appendTo('#tbl');
```

Please help, I am trying to add table to a div by append jquery. but its not working

Comment: You're missing `{ }` for your second `for` loop. Also, you should close HTML tag in jQuery selector.

Comment: @D4V1D Not having `{}` for the nested loop wouldn't affect anything. However, I agree with the second issue. `table` and `tbody` tags need to be closed.

Comment: @hjpotter92: I agree for the `{ }` but it helps readability and maintainability a lot however :)

Comment: You're trying to append the table to itself, or the div you're trying to append it to has the same id as the table.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the commented line, it will solve it. You are not attaching dynamically created element to existing DOM object. If you appened the dynamically created element to body you will be able to view it on the page

Comment: check stackoverflow requirements to give comment on others post. It clearly says you need 50reps. no one wants to give illusion to someone, think before you type

Comment: @PradeepSekar: Well, not having enough rep to comment **doesn't** mean you can use answer as comment. I just flagged it.

Comment: @D4V1D So other post says the same what I said are you going around and down voting?

Comment: @PradeepSekar: You indeed edited your answer to provide more information. I therefore removed my downvote. No need to go angry here.

Comment: @PradeepSekar You have 90 reputation at the moment, so you are able to post your remarks as a comment now.

Answer (score 0):

It works toggling comments in last two rows:

```
var rows = 10; //here's your number of rows and columns
var cols = 23;
var table = $('<table id="tbl"><tbody>');
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class="datarow">');
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        $('<td>Data</td>').appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(table); 
}

table.appendTo('body');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b5snhour/

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it like this:

```
var rows = 10; //here's your number of rows and columns
var cols = 23;
var markup = '<table id="tbl"><tbody>'; // Open Table
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    markup += '<tr class="datarow">'; // Add Each Row
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
       markup += '<td>Data</td>'; //Add Multiple column in each row
    }
    markup += '</tr>' //close Each Row <tr>
}
markup += '</tbody></table>'; //Close body and table.


$("body").append(markup); // Append it to body.
```

Hope it will work.